# Password keychan forgotten, not the login one ( ArubaKey )

Tags: mac, password-management, digital-signature, keychain

I have installed a bunch of certificates on my mac, due to italian legal system, in order to login to a certain website with a smartcard.

It all worked well for a few months and then yesterday it started to ask me the password for a keychain called SmartcardS00...and a bounce of letters. When I open the app keychain and I look into this locked keychain it shows me the certificates and in order to do something I need the password it asks me, but I don't know if I have ever know this pwd or not.

I tried to " delete " the keychain and try to reinstall all the certificates from the thumb drive with the smartcard, but I can't find the option to delete it anywhere.

PS I have MacOs X 10.11.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. The problem was that the pin on the smartkey was "locked", maybe some one inserted it wrong a couple of time. When I restored the pin with the PUK and then inserted the new pin on the website, it all worked out.

For your information the smartkey was the [ArubaKey](https://www.pec.it/CnsArubaKey.aspx) , if someone should have the same problem.